# CloudStack created 7 Debian Package instead of 16, why?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, deb, iaas, apache-cloudstack

To install cloudstack I use [this](https://cloudstack.apache.org/docs/en-US/Apache_CloudStack/4.2.0/html/Installation_Guide/sect-source-builddebs.html) installation guide. While building deb package, it says

This command will build 16 Debian packages. You should have all of the following, but I have only 7 of them:

```
   cloud-agent_4.0.0-incubating_amd64.deb   
   cloud-agent-deps_4.0.0-incubating_amd64.deb   
   cloud-agent-libs_4.0.0-incubating_amd64.deb   
   cloud-awsapi_4.0.0-incubating_amd64.deb   
   cloud-cli_4.0.0-incubating_amd64.deb   
   cloud-client_4.0.0-incubating_amd64.deb   
   cloud-client-ui_4.0.0-incubating_amd64.deb   
   cloud-core_4.0.0-incubating_amd64.deb   
   cloud-deps_4.0.0-incubating_amd64.deb   
   cloud-python_4.0.0-incubating_amd64.deb   
   cloud-scripts_4.0.0-incubating_amd64.deb   
   cloud-server_4.0.0-incubating_amd64.deb   
   cloud-setup_4.0.0-incubating_amd64.deb   
   cloud-system-iso_4.0.0-incubating_amd64.deb   
   cloud-usage_4.0.0-incubating_amd64.deb   
   cloud-utils_4.0.0-incubating_amd64.deb
```

What is the reason?
(In 4.1.1 version it says there must be 7 deb package, but in 4.2.0 it says 16.. It can be a mistake about CloudStack Guide?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 4.2, there are only 7 .deb packages.

How do we know?

Each package's name appears in [./debian/control](https://github.com/apache/cloudstack/blob/4.2/debian/control) of the source tree.  E.g.

```
Package: cloudstack-common
Architecture: all
Depends: bash, genisoimage, nfs-common
Conflicts: cloud-scripts, cloud-utils, cloud-system-iso, cloud-console-proxy, cloud-daemonize, cloud-deps, cloud-python, cloud-setup
Description: A common package which contains files which are shared by several CloudStack packages
```

If you look at the history of this file, you can see that the number of packages has reduced over time.  For example, in [version 4.0 there are 16 packages listed](https://github.com/apache/cloudstack/blob/4.0/debian/control).

Comment: Thanks, so it is not me, it is cloudstack? :)

Comment: The important thing to know how check whether the docs are accurate.  I logged the problem in Apache CloudStack's issue tracker [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CLOUDSTACK-4839)